# Same name for instance method and static method in python

Tags: python, class, static-methods

I am writing some small library and I want to provide users two approaches for the same functionality, by instance method and static method. Here is a simplified example:

```
class ClassTimesAdd(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
    def TimesAdd(self, c):
        return self.a * self.b + c
    
    @staticmethod
    def TimesAdd(a, b, c):
        return a * b + c

print(ClassTimesAdd.TimesAdd(1, 3, 7))
ins = ClassTimesAdd(2, 5)
print(ins.TimesAdd(7))
```

And you can find that the earlier function will be overwritten and only the last one is valid. I'm wondering if there is some simple method that I can use to make the two approaches both work.

Comment: You can kind of make it work with custom descriptors or weird metaclasses, but it's not worth the extra confusion and edge cases. Just pick two names.

Comment: static method is just function. just define it outside the class. so you will have a function and instance method. As already said, static method as addition to instance method just unnecessary complicate things.

Comment: As far as python is concerned, TimesAdd is just a single attribute attached to a single descriptor.  Writing your own descriptor is a pain.  Definitely not worth it.

Comment: Please understand the rationale why I need the same name. These functions are used by some customers, who don't need to remember too many different names but with same functionality.